# MS SQL Server View not allowing CONCAT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, view, casting, concatenation

MS SQL Server 2014.

I have a SQL statement that works fine:

```
SELECT CONCAT (
        CAST(T1.[F1] AS INTEGER),
        CAST(T1.[F2] AS INTEGER)
        ) AS F3 
FROM mytable AS T1
```

If I then put this into a view, and try to run I receive the error:

```
Operand data type int is invalid for concat operator
```

F1 and F2 both contain decimals but I want them concatenating e.g.:

```
F1 = 123.00000
F2 = 456.00000
```

Therefore `F3 = 123456`

Why does the view not allow this and is there a solution?

Comment: If you're wanting to treat them as *strings*, why are you telling `CAST` to convert them to *integers*?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever how else is possible?

Comment: Could you share the view script because CONCAT operator implictly convert the parameters to string.

Comment: [Can't reproduce this](https://rextester.com/SCPHFL81258)

Comment: @ZoharPeled put this in a view in SSMS then execute it, it will fail.

Comment: You would see that with  `SELECT {fn concat(1,1)}` so somehow it is getting mapped to that?

Comment: Right - don't use the visual designer is the answer here. It converts `CONCAT` to `fn CONCAT`. You also see this if pasting the code in the question into SSMS and selecting it  and using the "design query in editor" shortcut menu option

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use the visual designers.

They are [buggy](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/14/bad-habits-to-kick-using-the-visual-designers) and in this case convert

```
    SELECT CONCAT (
        CAST(T1.[F1] AS INTEGER),
        CAST(T1.[F2] AS INTEGER)
        ) AS F3 
FROM mytable AS T1
```

to

```
SELECT { fn CONCAT(CAST(T1.F1 AS INTEGER), CAST(T1.F2 AS INTEGER)) } AS F3
FROM     mytable AS T1
```

Calling the highly limited [ODBC escape sequence version of the function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/appendixes/string-functions?view=sql-server-ver15) (that only accepts two parameters which must be strings)

Just use a standard new query window to execute your `CREATE VIEW`/`ALTER VIEW`/`SELECT FROM` operations and you won't get this issue.

Comment: you think Microsoft would fix this

Comment: They seem to have put zero effort into the visual designers since probably 2005. If they aren't mangling your code they become useless as soon as you add constructs like `ROW_NUMBER` anyway

Comment: shame. #bloatware

Answer (score -1):

Please use concat function like below

SELECT {fn CONCAT('123 ', '456') }

Comment: In versions of SQL Server >= 2012 there is no need to use `fn CONCAT` at all. It has its own `CONCAT` function that is much superior